# Twitter posting to status/update URL is included in character length

Tags: php, twitter

Using PHP and `Abraham\TwitterOAuth` I'm posting a string of length 150 that includes a fully qualified URL `https://www.example.com`.

I'm receiving `Status is over 140 characters.`

I thought URL's where exempt of this limit? I've also tried posting the `URL` under the name of `url`, but its not being included.

Has anyone experienced this issue? I've searched their docs and cant find a post parameter for adding a URL to a status. Could it be that the API necessitates the status is a total of 140 and then will format the URL correctly.

Current workaround is to measure the length of URL and take from 140, then trim status at that length and append. Not great as would like to make use of as many chars as possible.

N.B. Could it be that twitter must have access to the URL? The current link is local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone runs into the same issue:

I found the following on a [twitter blog post](https://blog.twitter.com/express-even-more-in-140-characters) dated May 24, 2016. So it would appear this isn't possible :(

A URL at the end of Tweets generated from attaching photos, a video, GIF, poll, Quote Tweet, or DM deep link will also not count towards the character limit (URLs typed or pasted inside the Tweet will be counted towards the character limit as they do today).

There is word in the post of lifting this limit. So I'm sure/hope that shortly, this post will lose relevance.